# Let F : X → Y , C ⊆ Y , and D ⊆ Y . Suppose that C ⊆ D. Prove that $F^{-1} [C] ⊆ F^{-1} [D]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm assuming you want to assume basically all the info you're given, let x be in F^-1 [C] and prove it is in F^-1[D], where F^-1[C] is the inverse image operation.

Comment: Let $x \in F^{-1}(C)$. So, $F(x) \in C$. By hypothesis $C \subset D$ and therefore $F(x) \in D$. Thus $x \in F^{-1}(D)$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

This is statement is trivial, it's just a matter of understanding what each symbol means in this notation, and writing a chain of implications while understanding them.

Proof:
Let $x \in X$ is such that $x \in F^{-1}[C]$. This means nothing more than $F(x) \in C$.
But then $F(x) \in D$ (because $C\subseteq D$). The last by definition means that $x \in F^{-1}[D]$.
That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing:

Given: $C \subset D$.

Show $f^{-1}(C)\subset f^{-1}(D)$.

Let $x \in f^{-1}(C)$, then $f(x)\in C$.

Since $C \subset D$ : $f(x)\in D$, i.e.

$x \in f^{-1}(D)$.

Recall:

For $E \subset Y$:

$f^{-1}(E)=\{x | f(x) \in E \}$